# dropping the further rows once the required condition is met

Tags: pandas

Existing Dataframe :

```
Key           Status           Date

A1            start            10-10-2021
A1             in              10-10-2021
A1            success          10-10-2021
A1           re-start          10-10-2021
B1             start           15-10-2021
B1           completed         15-10-2021
B1             start           16-10-2021
C1           initiate          16-10-2021
C1           processed         16-10-2021
C1              start          16-10-2021
C1           login             16-10-2021
D1           start             30-10-2021
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Key           Status           Date

A1            start            10-10-2021
A1             in              10-10-2021
A1            success          10-10-2021
B1             start           15-10-2021
B1           completed         15-10-2021
C1           initiate          16-10-2021
C1           processed         16-10-2021
```

I am looking to drop all the other rows for each key once any of this status(**success, completed or processed**) appears in the status. also such key should be dropped which doesn't contain any of the status(that is success , completed or processed) ex. key D1

tried groupby with transform , but how to apply for multiple condition

```
df[df.groupby(['key']).Status.transform('last') == 'success']
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is filtering shifted values per groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html), last add condition for filter out groups if no match condition `cond`:

```
cond = ~df.Status.isin(["success","completed","processed"])
mask = cond.groupby(df.Key).transform(lambda x: x.shift(1, fill_value=True).cummin())

df = df[mask & df['Key'].isin(df.loc[~cond, 'Key'])]

print (df)
  Key     Status        Date
0  A1      start  10-10-2021
1  A1         in  10-10-2021
2  A1    success  10-10-2021
4  B1      start  15-10-2021
5  B1  completed  15-10-2021
7  C1   initiate  16-10-2021
8  C1  processed  16-10-2021
```

Alternative solution:

```
cond = df.Status.isin(["success","completed","processed"])
mask = cond.groupby(df.Key).transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=False).cummax())

df  = df[~mask & df['Key'].isin(df.loc[cond, 'Key'])]

print (df)
  Key     Status        Date
0  A1      start  10-10-2021
1  A1         in  10-10-2021
2  A1    success  10-10-2021
4  B1      start  15-10-2021
5  B1  completed  15-10-2021
7  C1   initiate  16-10-2021
8  C1  processed  16-10-2021
```